# AngularJS $timeout call function vs anonymous function vs expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout

```
var four = function() {
    $scope.text += '4';
}

var five = function() {
    $scope.text += '5';
}

$scope.text = '1';

$timeout(function () {
    $scope.text += '2'
});

$timeout($scope.text += '3');

$timeout($scope.$eval(four));

$timeout(five);
```

Result: 13425

According the call sequence the result should be 12345.
The lines below are executed immediately:

```
$timeout($scope.text += '3');
$timeout($scope.$eval(four));
```

And if you add the time parameter like below, the time is ignored.

```
$timeout($scope.text += '3', 1000);
$timeout($scope.$eval(four), 1000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uj9yx9c7/1/

Comment: That's how JavaScript works. That's why `$timeout` takes a function

Comment: What's an _"inline command"_?

Comment: I would refer to expression. I fixed the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$timeout($scope.text += '3');`

in this line `$scope.text += '3'` is not a function , but an expression. so it will get executed after `$scope.text = '1';`.

To defer a statement, you need to wrap that statement with a function and pass it `$timeout` or `setTimeout`. you can't defer a statement.

Replace `$timeout($scope.text += '3');` with `$timeout(function(){$scope.text += '3'})`. 
you will get the output `14235`.

And `$scope.$eval()` evaluates a function or an expression synchronously so 
`4` will get added before `235`.
changing it to

```
$timeout(function(){$scope.$eval(four)})
```

will get the expected output `12345`